# Sorting mongodb client findOne() in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building a server-less app in AWS with Lambda and Node.js. I currently have a MongoDB out at mLab. I am attempting to get the "latest" record based on an ISODate string. Using either findOne() or find w/limit 1 it returns the same record everytime (not the latest one).

I have 2 records in my test table that look like:

```
{ "field1": "myField", "versionTimestamp": "2017-06-13T18:33:06.223Z" }
{ "field1": "myField", "versionTimestamp": "2017-12-13T18:33:06.223Z" }
```

No matter what I do it always returns the one from the 6th

```
col.findOne(q, { "sort": ['versionTimestamp', 'desc'] }, function (err, doc) {
                    db.close();
                    if (err) {
                        sendErrorResponse("500", "Unable to query DB", err);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (doc) {
                            console.log(doc);
                            callback(null, doc.invoiceDocument);
                        }
                        else {
                            sendErrorResponse("404", "Record Not Found", "No records found that match those parameters.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Or with limit 1

```
col.find(q, { "limit": 1, "sort": ['versionTimestamp', 'desc'] }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                db.close();
                if (err) {
                    sendErrorResponse("500", "Unable to query DB", err);
                }
                else {
                    if (docs) {
                        console.log(docs[0]);
                        callback(null, docs[0].invoiceDocument);
                    }
                    else {
                        sendErrorResponse("404", "Record Not Found", "No records found that match those parameters.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: sort takes an array of sort preferences, default being 'asc'.  I'm guessing you want another set of array brackets: [ [ 'field', 'desc'] ]

Comment: findOne will only ever return the first document that matches the query criteria (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition), so you won't be able to pre-sort which results are returned. For the 2nd option, did you try changing 'desc' to 'asc' to see if it changed the results? You may want to try using 1 / -1 instead. Lastly, 'versionTimestamp' appears to be defined as Strings instead of date objects, was this intended?

Comment: @AdamHarrison Whilst the "strings" are indeed likely an error, they will still "lexically sort" due to the `"yyyy-mm-dd"` etc construction. So the comment from @asya is correct in that this is a "syntax error" causing the sort specification to be misinterpreted. See the [node docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne)

Comment: @AdamHarrison I did try sorting both ways. This is in the node driver, not the mongo shell so the call is different.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That was it! Thank you so much. They now both work.

Comment: Yeah, the dates were actually supposed to be epoch ints, I switched to ISOstrings for testing since I knew they would sort correctly as @NeilLunn mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asya found it! It was a malformed array in sort option:

> sort takes an array of sort preferences, default being 'asc'. I'm
>   guessing you want another set of array brackets: [ [ 'field', 'desc']
>   ] – Asya Kamsky yesterday